# Prove a trigonometric series is positive

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Let $f(x)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{inx}}{1+n^2}$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Prove $f(x)>0$ for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$.

This is an review question for my Fourier course. I am not sure how to approach this problem. The series is uniformly convergent, so $f(x)$ is continuous. Also $f(0)>0$. Do I need to draw a contradiction for $f(x)\le 0$ at some $x$?

Comment: Well @John, the series is, apparently, a complex one, so first one would have to be said why it gives *a real* value for any $\;x\in [-\pi\,,\,\pi]\;$ ...

Comment: You don't have to draw a contradiction; you could also just choose $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ and show that $f(x)>0$. Although the series is complex valued so are you only considering the real part to be positive?

Comment: Read my answer in a few minutes more, @JohnZHANG

Comment: By Euler's identity, $e^{inx} = \cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)$. The cosine term gives you the real part of the complex exponential while the sine term gives you the complex part. Typically it is notated as Re$\{e^{inx} \} = \cos(nx)$ and  Im$\{e^{inx} \} = \sin(nx).$ As long as you choose $n,x$ such that $\frac{-\pi}{2}<nx<\frac{\pi}{2}$ then you will have $\cos(nx)>0$, hence real part greater than zero. I just had an idea about how to solve this. I'll post it in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

$$\overline{f(x)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-inx}}{1+n^2}\stackrel{m:=-n}=\sum_{m=\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{e^{imx}}{1+m^2}=f(x)$$

Now, writing $\;e^{inx}=\cos nx+i\sin nx\;$ , we get that (by absolute convergence)

$$\sum_{n=\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}{1+n^2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{\sin nx}{1+n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}{1+n^2}=$$

$$=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{\sin(-nx)}{1+n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}{1+n^2}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}{1+n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}{1+n^2}=0$$

and, of course, we got another proof of the fact that the function is real.

The problem now is just to evaluate

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos nx}{1+n^2}=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos nx}{1+n^2}$$

**Positiviness:**:

$$1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos nx}{1+n^2}\ge1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n\pi}{1+n^2}=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{1+n^2}>1+2\left(-\frac12\right)=0$$

Using the estimation of the sum of an alternating series

Comment: Why $x=\pi$ gives global minimum?

Comment: Because $\;\cos\left((2n-1)\pi\right)=-1\;$ , the minimal value this function can attain.

Comment: But how about the effect of even terms?

Comment: Yup, you have a point there, @JohnZHANG. I'll have to mull on this a little more later as I can't see now a way out.